# sphinx delta index has same query as main index

Tags: sphinx

I am a newbie to sphinxsearch. But I learned to configure the conf and delta conf.

**My doubt**: I recently I came through a conf which has the same query in mainconf as well as deltaconf.

**sample**

```
main_conf:
{
    #...
    sql_query = select a,b,c from documents group by c
    #...
}
delta_conf : main_conf
{
    #...
    sql_query_killlist = select a from documents where date_updated > '2015-08-01 23:30:00'
    sql_query = select a,b,c from documents group by c
    #...
}
```

I need the understand how this works exactly. Will there be a duplication of data in the delta conf which was there in the main conf. How this works on indexing.

Thanks in advance.

Please be kind enough to answer this even if the question is basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got from sphinxsearch forum. *And I think it's clear*

> Will there be a duplication of data

Yes. As it stands.

You need to modify the delta sql_query to only include the new/updated records - the ones
NOT in the main index.

(the kill list is there to 'remove' the ones that need to be duplicated (because they
updated) from the main. If a record needs to be in both indexes, use killlist to return
it back to one)